# openAI gym TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

sorry I deleted this code I do not need help

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from env.BeamEnv import BeamEnv
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with nested ifs. LGTM

Comment: can you tell us why if is not a good design pattern here ?

Answer (score 1):

`if` statements are vital for an application. As they are part of [Dijkstra 1966](https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/it236/documents/structured.htm) model of structured programming ingredients (Sequence, Repeatation, Selection) which still applies today for other paradigm like OOP, POP, FP, FRP, ...

And you are not using them excessively (which could raise a red flag i.e `switch` statement).

However I would like to recommend to merge your two `if` conditions if you are not suppose render when you want to export frames. I don’t know what `_render()` function does but if it is only of use when you need to export frames, you should have put it in the main `if` to prevent calling unnecessary functions (`init_plt()` and `_render()`)

```
 if render and self.episode_count % self.sample_freq == 0:
        self._init_plt()
        self._render(obs)
        self.export_frames()
 self.episode_count += 1
```

If you adopt the above code I would like to put your conditions into a functions which returns a boolean.

```
 if self.should_render(self.episode_count):
      self.init_plt()
      self._render(obs)
      self.export_frames()
 
 self.episode_count += 1
```

Still if you always use `init_plt()` and  `_render()` together, you may consider, writing a wrapper function which calls them both. Just make the main logic of your code more readable. See Robert Martin (uncle bob) talks on clean codes.

Comment: should_render is a boolean and not callable unfortunately, can you suggest how I can change it to use should_render?

Comment: I meant you should write a function for `should_render` if there is a variable with the same name that I am not aware lets rename it to `should_render_export`

Comment: def shoudl_render_export(ep):

Comment: return render and self.epsidoe_count % selected_freq = 0

Comment: Now in your if statement just check what `should_render_export` returns. This is just to make your code more readable.

Comment: I updated my question with your code to test, and the new errors I am getting. I am fine with using my original code but I really want to learn how to write cleaner python code.

Comment: @AmyLee Clean code rules do not change by programming language. I would like to suggest you to see all 6 talks of Rober C Martin on the youtube (uncle bob). Search for uncle bob clean codes and see them all.

Comment: @AmyLee Where is your definition of function `should_render()`? There is also another site in stack exchange about code review, your question could be more relevant there. Share your complete codes and they will be help. You may also ask question about the error you are getting after the refactor process. I and others will be happy to help. Good luck